# `Is there any way... ` or `Are there any ways...`, which is correct?

Tags: questions, singular-vs-plural, existentials

I'm a self-learning programmer and every time I use Stack Overflow to post a question, on which I want to get whatever answers to achieve what I intend, I use both of these two statements:

`Is there any way to solve this issue?`

`Are there any ways to solve this issue?`

However, I wonder which one should be used in this case - I usually like to get multiple solutions if possible, so I lean to the latter, but I think that most people use the former instead.

So are both of the two statements correct in grammar? And if that's the case, which one is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are correct. First sounds better and is more common. Second can be used to emphasize that you are looking for multiple ways, but the first does not preclude multiple ways. *Is there any way to solve this issue? Yes, there are many.*

A third formation is

```
Is there no way to solve this issue?
```

A question with the expectation that in fact, there is a way.

Comment: How about "is there a way?"