# Would you tell me with the word ANY?

Tags: determiners

Any other crop

Any other crops

Would you tell me what is the difference between these?

Comment: With the second you are referring to more than one crop? Can you be more specific as to where you are confused?

Comment: Related: (1) ["is there any ways"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/18314/4559) (2) [singular or plural after any](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1155/4559)

Answer (score 3):

> [*Boll weevil damage exceeds the total value of any other **crops***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boll%20weevil%20damage%22%20%22any%20other%20crop%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>   [*Do you get a greater price per acre from that crop than from any other **crop** that you raise?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boll%20weevil%20damage%22%20%22any%20other%20crop%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22greater%20price%22%20%22than%20from%20any%20other%20crop%22&tbm=bks)

I think it would be "pedantic over-analysis" to suggest that switching *crop/crops* above would make any significant difference to the meaning of either sentence. But it's worth pointing out that [singular is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=any%20other%20crop,any%20other%20crops&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,any%20other%20crop;,c0;.t1;,any%20other%20crops;,c0) in most contexts.